# Store dynamic variables in dict in python

Tags: python

I'm passing 3 arguments which I want to store them in my_dict. Here, The port3 value is printing proper value as the passed argument. But when I try to insert in to my_dict, the values are storing as "port1" instead the value what I've passed in the arguments. How can I store the dynamic variable value to  my_dict

```
import os
import argparse
import operator
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
my_dict = {}
for i in range(1,4):
    parser.add_argument("-portid"+str(i), help="Provide Port id", required=True)
    
args = parser.parse_args()
port1 = args.portid1
port2 = args.portid2
port3 = args.portid3
print(port3)

for i in range(1,4):
    my_dict["portId"+str(i)] = 'port{0}'.format(i)
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: You basically already have everything you need in `args`! If you want it as a dict, do `vars(args)`. There is absolutely no reason to unpack `args` into individual variables and then trying to dynamically access those variables to put them into a dict.

Answer (score 2):

*`parser.parse_args()`* returns a [*`argparse.Namespace` instance which
just an object subclass with a readable string representation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) . If you want to get a dict-like view of the attributes you can use *`vars`* which returns *`__dict__`* attribute of the class.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'BAR'])
>>> vars(args)
{'foo': 'BAR'}
```